# What is the best practice for images that being used as a hero section?

Tags: html, css

i have this section that use an image for a hero section.
the problem is that the image is 1 Mb for the mobile, tablet and desktop.
i afraid if the image is to big.

i am wondering the best practice to use images as a hero section background.

thank you for the kind sugestion and opinion

Comment: That is pretty big, you can for sure compress the image more, at least half of that size but probably less.  Try a tool like this: https://compressjpeg.com/ or this: https://www.img2go.com/compress-image

Comment: thank you for the sugestion i will look into it. thank you cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, a 1MB-sized image for the hero banner is too large. Hero sections of a web page are typically the first visual elements that users will see. A large image will cause users to wait a long time and see nothing of your website, and they will leave very soon.

Therefore, it's important to optimize these images for both performance and aesthetic reasons. Your hero image should be less than 100KB.

TinyPNG is a good tool.
https://tinypng.com

You can also use responsive images for different aspect ratios.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="small.jpg" media="(max-width: 600px)">
  <source srcset="medium.jpg" media="(max-width: 1200px)">
  <source srcset="large.jpg">
  <img src="large.jpg" alt="Hero Image">
</picture>
```

If you are using Next.js, you can use the Image component https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image.

Finally, you can use lighthouse to test your webpage performance.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lighthouse/blipmdconlkpinefehnmjammfjpmpbjk

Comment: This is a new knowledge for me, will look into it. Thank you for the sugestion and the guidance. cheers